# ASP.NET MVC 5 with IdentityServer4: login url and access denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I'm integration `Identity Server 4` in my old `ASP.NET MVC` solution. I can say the login is working fine and happy for that. I only have two small issues:

1. when a user press Cancel in the **Login** page
2. a **Login** link

### when a user press Cancel in the Login page

In my application there are some links to `Authorize` pages. In this case I expect the user can see that pages only if it is authorize. As I expect, the user is redirect to the **Identity Server Login** page. If the credentials are valid, the site shows the protected pages. Job done!

[image: IdentityServer4 Login]

The problem I have when the user instead of login, press **Cancel** in the Login page. In this case the user is not authorize and the `Identity Server` returns `access_denied`. But as in this screenshot, there is an error from `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect`.

[image: Error when the user cancels an operation]

I tried to add in my `Startup` for `Owin` `OnAuthenticationFailed` but nothing changed.

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(PSC.Startup))]
namespace PSC {
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "http://auth.myurl.com, //ID Server
                ClientId = "ui",
                ClientSecret = "49C1A7E1-0C79-4A89-A3D6-A37998FB1975",
                ResponseType = "id_token code",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:44889/signin-oidc",
                Scope = "openid",
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            });
        }
        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(
                     AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, 
                     OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();

            if (context.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription != null && 
                context.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Account/ResetPassword");
            }
            else if(context.ProtocolMessage.Error == "access_denied" && 
                    context.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.StartsWith("AADB2C90091"))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
            }
            else if(context.Exception.Message == "access_denied")
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/");
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + 
                                          context.Exception.Message);
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I handle this problem?

### Login link

Usually in `_LoginPartial.cshtml` there is a link to the local site for a login like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", new { 
                 returnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl }, 
                 htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
```

How can I have the correct link to the login page with `IdentityServer`? I noticed the link to `IdentityServer` is quite complex with more information that a return url.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user hits cancel?  Is a cancel button even needed?  I would just shitcan the cancel button, let the user hit the back button in that case

Comment: I should display a page to inform the user its credentials are not valid and/or to show `ReturnUrl`. Hidden the cancel button could be ok but, generally speaking, it can't resolve the problem.

Comment: However, you didn't post template code for the "Cancel" button. It appears it takes you to the auth-protected part of your web, instead of the public part, where it would be logical for the user to end up by canceling a login process.

Comment: A cancel button has nothing to due with openId connect.  It will simply do whatever you tell it to do.  Can you please post the code that is fired both front and back end once the cancel button is clicked.  It is sending you back to the signin endpoint for your application.  It is interesting that you are asking about why your cancel button does a certain behavior without showing any code regarding the cancel button

Comment: I didn't change anything about `Cancel` button; it is the default behaviour. Happy to share more code but I don't know what I can show. I found this issue because I should try what it is happing if a user changes its mind and it doesn't want to insert any credentials.